# facing problems in sentiment analysis in python

Tags: python-2.7, markov

I am facing problem in performing Morkov model

```
import markovify
import sys

# Read text from file
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    sys.exit("Usage: python generator.py sample.txt")
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    text = f.read()

# Train model
text_model = markovify.Text(text)

# Generate sentences
print()
for i in range(5):
    print(text_model.make_sentence())
    print()
```

I get the following error report

```
 An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: Usage: python generator.py sample.txt
```

please solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Execute your code in command line with this command.

```
python generator.py sample.txt
```

Here generator.py python file in the code and sample.txt file is dataset file

Comment: I tried in the command line as well but it is not running there

Comment: When I run the command on the command line I get the following message
Usage: python generator.py sample.txt